# CSV/XLXS into SQL Table : Best Way based on the format

Tags: sql, loops, csv, xlsx

I have the following case

I have the following csv file format example:

```
Year;Ligue1;Ligue2;Ligue3
2017;Manchester;Burnley;Doncaster
2016;Chelsea;Aston Villa;Leeds
2015;Arsenal;Newcastle;Sheffield
```

What I would like to create so far is a table/view  with rows just for each year and each Ligue.
For instance : Year : **2017** ; Ligue : **League** 1 ; Team : **Manchester**

My idea is the following.

To bulk the CSV file into the database : Bulk into ...

Once the data is loaded I would iterate through all the records from first column (Ligue1 ) until the last column (Ligue 3) and insert these records into a specific view depending on the league classification.

For instance i will create the following view:

View  **Football** with just 3 columns : **Year** , **League**, **Winner**

Insert into Football (**Year**, **League** = *always the name of the Column (League 1, League 2 or League 3*) **Team** ) where Team is the relevant Winner for the specific year.

Final Result Example:

```
Year;League;Winner
2017;League1;Manchester
2017;League2;Burnley
2017;League3;Doncaster
```

Would be the idea of bulking the CSV the best approach?

How could I get the results and cases described in the second step? With Counters / Cursors...?

Comment: What kind of sql database (mysql, oracle, sql server, sqlite)?  Are you using a software tool to connect to it?  Many tools offer csv import options which can help automate the column naming process.  And you can use the command line as well.

Comment: Sorry Dean, it is SQL Server